# Не могу установить шаблоны консоли в visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

Что надо установить чтобы были шаблоны консолей для проектов в visual studio?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно все идет из коробоки. Установите последний `.NET SDK 6.0`.

[Документация](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net60#install-with-visual-studio) установки.

[Ссылка на скачивание .NET](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet)